# Why is my navbar scaling the page on mobile?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, navbar

My website has a scaling problem on the chrome browser in android on mobile. This does not happen in Firefox on mobile or in any desktop browser. When the navbar is selected and drops down, it scales the webpage. Note that the page is scaled differently depending on which dropdown has been selected. It seems as though the navbar has invisible content that is breaking frame when the dropdown behavior is engaged.

I have stitched together 4 screenshots of the issue.

Help with either a fix or a workaround would be much appreciated.

[image: scaling issue]

```css
#NavigationBarList{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
}

li{
font-size:130%;
}

nav a{
display:block;
}

/* This customizes the presentation of the list elements (menu items) in the navbar. */
nav li{
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:200%;
color:#7F1717;
background-color:#9E939E;
width:25%;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
z-index:11;
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 1px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000000;
box-shadow:         inset 0 0 1px #000000;
}

nav ul{
width:100%;
}

/* Hide the sub menu items. */
nav ul ul {
display:none;
}

nav ul ul ul {
display:none
}

/* When hovered over, the CSS menu will drop down. */
nav li:hover > ul {
text-align:center;
font-size:40%;
display:block;
}

/* Don't underline links in the list elements (menu items). */
ul a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#7F1717;
}

/* Change the background color of hovered list elements. This was both active and hover... */
nav li:hover{
background-color:#625C62;
}

/* This customizes the ul elements in the sub-menu. */
nav ul ul{
position:absolute;
padding:0;
width:100%
}

nav ul ul ul{
position: absolute;
width:400%;
left:100%;
top:0;
}

#totheleft{
left:-100%;
}

nav ul ul ul li{
text-align:center;
font-size:250%;
}

/* I think this refers to the dropdown navbar location and properties. */
nav ul ul li {
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="NavigationBarList">
    <li style="float:left;">Events
    <ul>
   <li><a href="tournaments.html">Tournaments</a></li>
   <li><a href="kids_hour.html">Kid's Hour</a></li>
   <li><a href="calendar.html">Local Calendar</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li style="float:left;">Programs
 <ul>
   <li><a href="summer_camps.html">Summer Camps</a></li>
   <li>In Schools
   <ul>
  <li><a href="schools.html">After School</a></li>
  <li><a href="school_registration.html">Registration</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="instructors.html">Local Instructors</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li style="float:left;">Content
 <ul>
   <li><a href="posts.html">Posts</a></li>
   <li><a href="games.html">Games</a>
 </ul>
 </li>
    </li>
 <li style="float:left;">Connect
 <ul>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
   <li>Resources
   <ul id="totheleft">
     <li><a href="links.html">Chess</a></li>
     <li><a href="go_links.html">Go</a></li>
     <li><a href="xiangqi_links.html">Xiangqi</a></li>
  <li><a href="shogi_links.html">Shogi</a></li>
     <li><a href="backgammon_links.html">Backgammon</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="about us.html">About Us</a></li>
 </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I came up with was to set overflow-x:hidden on my overlay. I had tried this previously on the body, but on Android overflow-x does not work on the body; it must be set for a container. There is presumably a related reason that this issue only arose on Android. This workaround works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the `head` section of all your pages.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0">
```

From the [google developers site](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/ConfigureViewport)

> Without a viewport, mobile devices will render the page at a typical  desktop screen width, scaled to fit the screen.

So when you visit the webpage on mobile, the view is actually zoomed out to fit all your content. When you touch your navbar, the browser also tries to zoom in. Setting `user-scalable=0` prevents this from happening.

The downside is your users will no longer be able to scale the zoom on the website on mobile, but the only alternative would be to rewrite your website to use a fluid layout.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't affect the website rendering in any way that I could see.

Comment: All it does is prevent the website from scaling when you select the navbar on mobile. It didn't work?

Comment: No, it didn't affect my issue. The action of dropping down the navbar still caused the site shift. Perhaps scaling is not the correct way to describe my issue, but it is the best description I could manage.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<ul>`s that contain the dropdown items have width=100%. This means the width will be 100% of the first relatively positioned parent (which in this case is the `<body>`). This is causing an overflow on the x axis.

You could make the `<ul>`s 25% width and the `<li>`s inside 100%, instead of what you have now where the `<li>`s are 25%.

Giving you

```
/* This customizes the ul elements in the sub-menu. */
nav ul ul{
position:absolute;
padding:0;
width:25%;
}
```

and

```
/* I think this refers to the dropdown navbar location and properties. */
nav ul ul li {
position:relative;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: This fix sounds so on target, but it didn't affect the issue I am experiencing :(

Answer (score 1):

I went to your site and checked it out real quick... I noticed you are using absolute positioning to position your content in the center of your page. I assume this is what is causing your issue.

I would look up a tutorial on how to create a repeating background image and use that instead of trying to use one image with no repeat. then you can center your content with margin: 0 auto.

I know its not a definite answer but I hope it nudges you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, and giving me a direction. I am using absolute positioning to center the white overlay, but the red and white background is set to repeat.

Comment: Hmm.. I will have a chance to look into this further today. The power just went out so i dont have internet access on my comput at the moment. Which element are you using to display your background?

Comment: I just added the background image to the body. Regarding the positioning - I have the overlay positioned absolutely relative to the body. All of the actual website content is in that. The navbar is absolutely positioned except that the nav ul ul li has relative positioning.

Comment: @SamCopeland I would refrain from using absolute positioning at all costs. I cant guarentee this is the source of your problems but i stronly sugest you persue this path.

Comment: I've been playing around with the suggestion, and I don't understand why the positioning should be at fault. I have an absolutely positioned overlay that I center over my background. I put my content in that. It needs to be absolutely positioned so that I can control the center.

I also use absolute positioning on the navbar so that the dropdowns don't displace the content. Isn't that standard procedure? Again, I appreciate the feedback.